# Add Opportunity Record with C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to Create an Opportunity record from C# for CRM 2011. This is the code I am using:

```
Entity opportunity = new Entity("opportunity");

    opportunity["new_source"] = p.LeadOriginDetail;
    opportunity["opportunityratingcode"] = new OptionSetValue(3);
    opportunity["new_leadstatus"] = new OptionSetValue(100000000);
    opportunity["statuscode"] = p.Type;

    opportunity["ownerid"] = "Lead Share";
    Guid opportunityId = orgService.Create(opportunity);
```

I keep getting this error "Customer not specified." How do you add Opportunity records. The same code works for adding records to Accounts.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familar with this CRM but I'm feeling that you've to specify something like `opportunity["Customer"] = ...`

Comment: Thanks, Customer isn't an attribute in the Opportunity Entity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it.

Had to add:

```
opportunity["customerid"] = new EntityReference("account", accountId);
```

Comment: Sure. You have to wait until then